# Overflowing layout inside constraint layout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have two layouts inside a constraint layout.

One is reserved for the actual screens, and the other is reserved for the bottom toolbar

the problem is the actual screen is flowing under the toolbar and i want them to be next to each other.

What do I need to change in this layout ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainScreen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainFrame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:background="#ff00ff00" />


    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/green"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forget to add where should be place navigation bottom view, try this.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainFrame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:background="#ff00ff00" />


<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/green"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mainFrame"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />
```

Comment: it doesnt work, it places the navigation bar in the middle of the screen

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is a bit old and probably solved, but thought it was worth answering for those who stumble across it...

The problem here is that the FrameLayout is set to wrap_parent which means it will only grow as large as it needs to in order to display its content.

You can use a contraint weight to have it grow as large as it can, something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/mainScreen"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
     android:id="@+id/mainFrame"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="0dp"
     app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1"
     app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_navigation"
     app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
     tools:background="#ff00ff00" />


<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/steel"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mainFrame"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_main_drawer" />
```

with the important part being `android:layout_height="0dp"` and `app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1"`, and also adding the suggestion posted by Hemant.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is set the height of the frame layout to `0dp` -> Constraint layout takes it at `match_constraint`.